# how to deploy field set to Production contained in managed package after adding some more fields?

Tags: deployment

Can anyone let us know how to deploy field set to Production contained in managed package after adding some more fields in it as this field set is not visible in components of outbound change set?

Comment: As far as I know, you can't.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Any workaround you can think of to accomplish this?

Comment: Hi @PankajGanwani. I guess you can use Metadata API to accomplish that. Either via Workbench, SFDX, Gearset or any other CI tool must be working fine for that